# How do I Assert in a CanvasLifecycleHandler test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, canvas, test-setup, canvaslifecyclehandler

I have a CanvasLifecycleHandler thst rewrites the url with a timeStamp.  Is it possible to assert in the test class that the url has been changed?  If so, how?

CanvasLifecycleHandler

```
    public class CANV_LIFECYCLE_Registration
implements Canvas.CanvasLifecycleHandler {
    public Set<Canvas.ContextTypeEnum> excludeContextTypes(){
        Set<Canvas.ContextTypeEnum> excluded = new Set<Canvas.ContextTypeEnum>();
        return excluded;
    }

    public void onRender(Canvas.RenderContext renderContext) {
        Canvas.ApplicationContext app = renderContext.getApplicationContext();
        Canvas.EnvironmentContext env = renderContext.getEnvironmentContext();    
        // get urlpath from canvas app
        string newURL = getURLPath(app.getCanvasUrl());

        //add random string to prevent caching
        newURL += '?R='+ DateTime.now().gettime();

        //update the url
        app.setCanvasUrlPath(newURL);
    }

    private string getURLPath(string canvasURL){
        String[] URLList = canvasUrl.split('/');
        string URLPath = '';
        for(Integer a = 3; a < URLList.size(); a++){
            URLPath += '/' + URLList[a];
        }
        return URLPath;
    }
}
```

What I have so far for Test Class (strait from docs here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_testing_your_canvaslifecyclehandler.htm))

```
    @isTest
private class CANV_LIFECYCLE_Registration_TEST {
    static testMethod void testDefaultMockValues(){
        // Test handler using the default mock RenderContext Canvas.Test creates
        CANV_LIFECYCLE_Registration handler = new CANV_LIFECYCLE_Registration();
        Canvas.Test.testCanvasLifecycle(handler,null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the Canvas.ApplicationContext `app` variable as a property in CANV_LIFECYCLE_Registration. If it is public you could then read this directly in the test class to make an assertion.

```
CANV_LIFECYCLE_Registration handler = new CANV_LIFECYCLE_Registration();
Canvas.Test.testCanvasLifecycle(handler,null);
System.assertEquals('The expected URL with timestamp', handler.appProperty.getCanvasURL());
```

Alternatively, you could create a Canvas.RenderContext using `Canvas.Test.mockRenderContext()`. On this mock you can directly call `getApplicationContext().getCanvasURL()`.